# Oracle : Query to get the Last Friday of the week if I give any date

Tags: sql, oracle

If I give a date let's say '13-Mar-2019' my query needs to retrieve the value '15-Mar-2019'. Which is the last Friday of the week.

Comment: The *last* Friday is the week's *only* Friday - every week has just one Friday ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trancate the date to the ISO week, which gets you the week's Monday (as an ISO week starts with Monday). Then add four days:

```
select trunc(date '2019-03-13', 'iw') + 4 from dual;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. The query is giving the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`next_day()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions093.htm).  It is the Oracle function specifically designed for this purpose.

```
select next_day(date '2019-03-13', 'Fri')
from dual;
```

The only nuance is that if the date is *Friday*, then it will return the next Friday.  That might be what you want.  Otherwise, just subtract one day:

```
select next_day(date '2019-03-13' - 1, 'Fri') as friday_end_of_week
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below -

```
select trunc(to_date('13-Mar-2019'), 'iw') + 4 from dual
```

Comment: Don't use `TO_DATE` without a format, because then you rely on the session's `NLS_TERRITORY` setting and your query can fail. With a month name, you'd even have to specify the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` to play it save. The proper `TO_DATE` expression would be `TO_DATE('13-Mar-2019', 'dd-Mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language=english')`. For a fixed date, use a date literal instead: `date '2019-03-13'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY( to_date('2019-03-13', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_char(to_date('2019-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'DAY')) FROM dual;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c13870f514bae68744ae6089001a36fe)